# C# Making a Most Played section for a music player project (Array sort and passing the array to a list)

Tags: c#, listbox, audio-player

I am trying to make a Music Player program in C#. The project I am currently doing is for personal use and won't be published in public.
To show you guys what I've done so far is:

UI: [image]

This is the UI of the program, at the left there are two buttons My Music & Favourites (Which is supposed to be the most played songs). What I need help with is to sort the list items from the biggest to smallest meaning that the most played of all of them has to be first on the list (Data stored in a txt file, info provided in the what've tried section) and I am not sure how to do that with a list. Ignore the windows media player control in the bottom right, I use it to play the music files and hide on the program start.

I have a listbox control that has different songs in it, each time an item is clicked from the list, the selected item plays. I am currently saving each song's data in a .txt file. Also when the Favourites button is clicked the program clears the current list (It doesn't open a new form) and adds the data from a folder (if the song was never played before it won't have a .txt file generated so it won't be added). I managed to list the most played songs in the list. So I have a .txt file for each song that has the number of times the song was played in the first line.

Apart from that I've tried making a 2D string array which has 2 columns, song name first and number of plays as second. I've tried to sort the array but the results are not sorted when I tried to add the array items to the list.

```
//This is my sort class:

string[,] _sortArray;
int[] _tagArray;
int _sortIndex;

protected string[,] SortArray { get { return _sortArray; } }

public ArraySort(string[,] theArray, int sortIndex)
{
    _sortArray = theArray;
    _tagArray = new int[_sortArray.GetLength(0)];
    for (int i = 0; i < _sortArray.GetLength(0); ++i) _tagArray[i] = i;
    _sortIndex = sortIndex;
}

public string[,] ToSortedArray()
{
    Array.Sort(_tagArray, this);
    string[,] result = new string[
    _sortArray.GetLength(0), _sortArray.GetLength(1)];
    for (int i = 0; i < _sortArray.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < _sortArray.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            result[i, j] = _sortArray[_tagArray[i], j];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public virtual int Compare(int x, int y)
{
        if (_sortIndex < 0) return 0;
        return CompareStrings(x, y, _sortIndex);
}

protected int CompareStrings(int x, int y, int col)
{
        return _sortArray[x, col].CompareTo(_sortArray[y, col]);
}

//Calling the method from the main program and storing the array data to the 
//list
ArraySort comparer = new ArraySort(array, 1);
string[,] sortedData = comparer.ToSortedArray();
for (i = 0; i < sortedData.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    listSongs.Items.Add(sortedData[i,0]);
}
```

I expected the array items to be sorted from the biggest to smallest but that does not seem to be the case since the list is sorted randomly.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using a 2D string array, and not creating a model class ... perhaps a List<Song>? And have you looked at using LINQ to simplify your sorting needs? I'm just wondering if I'm missing some requirement here.

Comment: I couldn't use LINQ because I was trying to compare a certain column from the 2d array with string values which I knew for sure that the column had always numbers (The number of times the song was played), I had to make the array a string type because I wanted to know the name of the song that was in the next column. I am going to try your and @Abion47's idea below to save the data into a class instead of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a 2D array. Make a class to hold the data and make an array of that:

```
class SongPlayData {
    string SongName;
    int PlayCount;
}

// ...

SongPlayData[] playData = // your song data here
```

Then you can sort the array like so:

```
SongPlayData[] ToSortedArray() {
    var sortedData = SongPlayData[playData.length];
    Array.Copy(playData, sortedData, 0);
    Array.Sort(sortedData, (a, b) => a.PlayCount.CompareTo(b.PlayCount));
    return sortedData;
}
```

And here's the obligatory LINQ version:

```
SongPlayData[] ToSortedArray() {
    return playData.OrderBy(d => d.PlayCount).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, not exactly what I need but I will save the data into a class instead of an array. Thanks for your awesome help!